# Jquery, xml and variables

Tags: jquery, xml, variables

I'm trying to use xml data to insert as a variable for an animation but am fairly clueless. What am I doing wrong and how far off am I?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('mon').each(function(){
                var top = $(this).find('positiontop').text();
                var opac = $(this).find('opacity').text();
                var dur = $(this).find('duration').text();
                $(".mon img").animate({ top: "'+top+'",opacity: '+opac+'}, '+dur+' );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

and here is my xml

```
<data>
    <mon>
        <positiontop>180</positiontop>
        <opacity>0.6</opacity>
        <duration>1500</duration>
    </mon>
.....
....
</data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this slightly changed snippets should help and works for me..

.mon
    {
        position:relative;
    }

```
.mon img
{
    position:relative;      
}
</style>

<div class="mon">
    <img  src="my_image.gif" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('mon').each(function() {
                   var positiontop = $(this).find('positiontop').text();
                   var opac = $(this).find('opacity').text();
                   var duration = $(this).find('duration').text();
                   $(".mon img").animate({ top: positiontop, opacity: opac }, parseInt(duration));
               });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That does indeed work, thanks!. 
I'm new to the site so how do I give you rep?

Comment: no idea mate, blind leading the blind here, my first day on the site too :-)

Answer (score 0):

the animate function sets some sort of callback and your code will continue to run, that will most likely have x number of .animate function calls running at the same time.